# Woocommerce showing notices and cart from another users sessions

Tags: woocommerce

I'm having an issue with logging in.  On occasion, more often every day, users are logging in and getting User notices, shopping carts, and even saved addresses from another user.  It's not possible that these users have logged in across each others machines.

To try and fix this, we've recently updated W3 Total Cache settings to reflect woocommerce recommendations, and updated php-fpm cache settings to skip pages for users with the wc_sessions_ cookie.

Has anyone come across this before?  The cookies in the browser all seem to match the user who is logged in, as does the messaging everywhere on the site except the items in the cart, shipping addresses, and the You are now Logged in As  messages.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently experiencing the same exact issue and the possible culprit that I keep finding in my research is varnish caching, which may need to be disabled for specific views such as Cart, Checkout, etc. Unfortunately, this is not a solid answer as I haven't solved the problem yet either but hopefully it points you in the right direction.